# Creating Polygons from black/white map or points using QGIS?

Tags: qgis, polygon-creation

I just started working with qgis and I have two maps of a town. On the one map buildings are outlined by Points, like this.

[image: Building edges by points]

And the other map is just black with White Buildings. like this.

[image: black and white]

My task is now to create a layer in which the buildings are polygons. I looked up some questions here and found some interesting stuff, but it never really worked for me. I tried some tools in qgis, like lines to Polygons, but it never worked.

Can you think of a way to auto-create a layer like this or should I just do it by hand?

Of course I'm asking this because it's a very big amount of data and I would rather not do it by hand.

===================

This is what the identifier gives me. "Kanal" is german for "channel" or "band" I think.

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Assuming the buildings in your raster has a cell value of `190` (as you have shown in your image), you could try doing the following:

---

1. Use the **Raster Calculator** to create a new raster only containing cells which have `190` (i.e. the output should only contain the buildings):

   ```
   Raster > Raster Calculator...
   ```

   And use the following expression:

   ```
   "raster@1" / ("raster@1" = 190)
   ```

---

2. **Polygonize** the output raster from Step 1:

   ```
   Raster > Conversion > Polygonize (Raster to vector)
   ```

   [image: Polygonize]

---

---

Example:

1. Original raster:

   [image: raster]
2. Output of raster calculator:

   [image: output]
3. Polygonized:

   [image: Result]

Comment: Oh yeah, that's a good idea! Sadly it's not the same black everywhere. 

Does somebody maybe know a way to just polygonize a selection of points, or maybe draw lines in a selection of points in order to use the Lines To Polygons tool?

I used the plugin Points2One, but that takes all the points in the into account and makes one line out of it.

Comment: @FinnGolovkin - What cell values are used for the buildings in your raster? Because we could use the **Raster Calculator** to change the cell values of your raster.

Comment: I'm sorry but I'm not really sure what you mean by cell value. Do I already have cells? Can I inspect them somehow? Still pretty green :/

Comment: @FinnGolovkin - No problem! Your raster is made up of pixels (or cells) since it's basically an image file. If you use the **Identify Features** tool from the toolbar (`View > Identify Features`) and click somewhere on a raster, you should see some information like the band number (e.g. `Band 1`) and its value. If you click on some of your buildings, you can see what cell value they have and vice versa with any cells in your raster :)

Comment: Ah great, thank you!
I'll try to post a picture here so i can show you what it says.

Comment: Alright I edited my original post with some information.

Comment: @FinnGolovkin - Those look like values for your point layer, not your raster ;). If you want to do it with points, it's probably best to upload your point shapefile to a public server so that others could test it as converting your points into lines then into polygons can be _very_ tricky.

Comment: Oh alright, yes that's correct, I only know of points, so a raster seems to be something different. Sadly I don't know if I even have any raster data... or do I automatically? :D

Comment: @FinnGolovkin - What is your black and white map?

Comment: Yes right! I'll post a pic again! Looks better! Every building has the band 1 value of 190 I think. The black area is always something different.

Comment: @FinnGolovkin - Edited the post which hopefully might help =)

Comment: Oh man! It worked! Wow , this is exactly what I needed!! Thank you so much Joseph!

Comment: @FinnGolovkin - Most welcome and nice one! We got there in the end ;)